# Why is image uploaded to window with QLabel and QPixmap automatically rotating?

Tags: python, image, pyqt5, qpixmap, qlabel

I am trying to create an app in PyQt5 which allows a user to click on a QPushButton and then view all their image files on their computer in a separate window before picking an image to be displayed in a QLabel in the window. At the moment I can upload the files, however some of them end up automatically rotating 90 degrees anticlockwise.

Here is the part of code that is responsible for adding the image to the QLabel:

```
def openImage(self):
    fName = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open Image', '', 'Image Files (*.jpg)')
    self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap(fName[0]).scaled(700, 700, Qt.KeepAspectRatio))
```

If anybody knows how to make sure that all images stay in the correct orientation instead of rotating, your help is very much appreciated.
Thanks,
Roy

Comment: This code does not rotate the images, you could show the image you upload and an image of what you get in your widget.

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to upload an image to the post as you need at least 10 reputation.

Comment: Upload it to other sites and share the link

Comment: http://imgur.com/4AEu4Rr

Comment: You can share the original image

Comment: the one on the left is the original image and the one on the right is the image when it has been added to my program

Comment: I do not want the cropped or edited image, but the original image.

Comment: Do you mean the image I am trying to put into my app or the full screen of my laptop as the one on the left is not cropped or edited

Comment: I want you to upload the original image to http://imgur.com to see if what your image viewer places correctly or is that you have placed some property by default.

Comment: http://imgur.com/S6IliOg

Comment: I get to show the image correctly: http://imgur.com/a/heYPw

Comment: When I upload the image to imgur and then download that image, I get it displayed correctly as well. It's very confusing.

Comment: The image is probably corrupted, so you get that look.

Comment: Yh must be. Thanks.

Comment: You can share the original compressed image in a .zip file through drive, dropbox, etc. To be able to analyze it, please.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/s9xe0lkcj4fm42q/IMG_0039.JPG.zip?dl=0